# CSS responsive table layout thrown off by elements being hidden at start

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-table

I have tables that are responsive using the guide below. The issue I am having is that I want to have rows that are hidden with jQuery show/hide (so display:none applied). The only issue I have is that when the hidden rows are shown, they are skewed to the left and don't take up the whole width. This is not an issue on the unhidden rows. If I remove the hide they show up correctly on mobile, because the display:none/display:block is not affected. I am just wondering how I can make it so the newly shown rows take up the entire width.

I was trying to apply css to the rows that would be shown, but the issue is the exact css I need on those cells is already there. It just doesn't apply it right when they are switched from display:none to display:block AFTER the table is made. I was trying css visibility hidden instead of jquery hide, but then I ran into even more issues. Does anyone have any ideas for this?

https://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/
https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

EDIT: Based on people's opinions. Here is a code snippet:

```
<style>
  @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    
    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    #no-more-tables table, 
    #no-more-tables thead, 
    #no-more-tables tbody, 
    #no-more-tables th, 
    #no-more-tables td, 
    #no-more-tables tr { 
        display: block;
    }
 
    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    #no-more-tables thead tr { 
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }
 
    #no-more-tables tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
 
    #no-more-tables td { 
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%; 
        white-space: normal;
        text-align:center;
    }
 
    #no-more-tables td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%; 
        padding-right: 10px; 
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align:left;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
 
    /*
    Label the data
    */
    #no-more-tables td:before { content: attr(data-title); }
}
</style>
<table id="no-more-tables" style="width:400px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>header01</th>
            <th>header02</th>
            <th>header03</th>
            <th>header04</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="header01">cell data</td>
            <td data-title="header02">cell data</td>
            <td data-title="header03">cell data</td>
            <td data-title="header04">cell data</td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="hiddenRow">
            <td data-title="header01">hidden data</td>
            <td data-title="header02">hidden data</td>
            <td data-title="header03">hidden data</td>
            <td data-title="header04">hidden data</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
            <td data-title="header01">cell data</td>
            <td data-title="header02">cell data</td>
            <td data-title="header03">cell data</td>
            <td data-title="header04">cell data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="unhideButton">
toggle the row
</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js" integrity="sha256-1XMpEtA4eKXNNpXcJ1pmMPs8JV+nwLdEqwiJeCQEkyc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".hiddenRow").hide();
  $(".unhideButton").click(function() {
      $(".hiddenRow").toggle();
  });
</script>
```

Any suggestions/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) preferably as a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: I agree with Brett. I tried to convert your code into a snippet, fixed your typo, but the resulting code did not make much sense to me. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Sorry about that, I should have included one to make it easier to see. I just wrote up a better example and tested it in codepen and w3 tryit editor. Both showed the issue I have where the row that gets added is skewed to the left.